# How can I make this call thread save?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using a customized message box that I found on this page incl sources:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/creating-customized-message-box-with-animation-effect-in-windows-form

In the most cases it works fine but sometimes when I have 2 messages boxes popping up at the same time, then I have a crash in this function:

```
 class MsgBox : Form
 {

    private static MsgBox _msgBox;

    public static MsgDlgResult Show(string message, string title, Buttons buttons, IconImage icon)
    {
        _msgBox = new MsgBox();
        _msgBox._lblMessage.Text = message;
        _msgBox._lblTitle.Text = title;

        MsgBox.InitButtons(buttons);
        MsgBox.InitIcon(icon);

        _msgBox.Size = MsgBox.MessageSize(message);
        _msgBox.ShowDialog();
        MessageBeep(0);
        return _buttonResult;
    }

    private static void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        switch (btn.Name)
        {
            case "Abort":
                _buttonResult = MsgDlgResult.Abort;
                break;

            case "Retry":
                _buttonResult = MsgDlgResult.Retry;
                break;

            ......

        }


       ----->>>> _msgBox.Dispose();
     }
 }
```

I get the error message 
System.InvalidOperationException: "Cross-thread operation not valid: control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"

How can I make this class thread safe or at least this call in c#? But it must be still able that I can have more than one message box at a time.

**Update**
My calls:

```
 MessageBoxResult result = MsgBox.Show("My Message test", string.Empty, MsgBox.Buttons.OK, MsgBox.IconImage.Error);
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you open your custom messagebox?

Comment: That article is completely inappropriate for WPF. WPF already supports rich animations in XAML. What are you trying to do? Perhaps all you need is a couple of XAML lines. There's no reason to use threads either, even in Windows Forms

Comment: I don't need animation, I use it because I can add additional buttons to the message box and change the colors and style

Comment: Then it's even more inappropriate. Just create your own dialog box - just create a Window with the controls you need and display it

Comment: I would like to know why my question was down voted. What was wrong? I would like to learn for the next time

Answer (score -1):

Let me guess...

- you create 1st dialog box and it is assigned it to the `_msgBox` variable.
- You then create a second dialog box and again, you assign it to the same `_msgBox` variable (since it is `static`).
- you click the button in the first dialog
- the event handle fires and tries to dispose the second dialog box
- you get the exception

The private variables in this solution should not be made static. If they are static - all instances of this class refer to the same instance of the variable, here to the same `_msgBox` and `_buttonResult`.

Make sure that there is a private constructor for the class that is called when static `Show` is called. In this constructor you should assign respective values.
Or assign values when you declare the variables.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right. So you mean I should remove the static complete and instead do something like MsgBox myBox = new MsgBox and then MyBox.Show()?

Comment: No, don't remove static completely. First of all, static should be used out of necessity and not out of convenience. Remove static from variables like _msgBox, _buttonResult, _timer etc. since you are going to have more instances of the message box at a time. Those should be instantiated per object. The method Show is ok to be static since it eases the call to the class and creates new object "behind the screen" anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The solution below is extremely smelly, but here you are:

**Step 1:** Rename the existing method `Show` to `ShowUnsafe`.

```
public static MsgDlgResult ShowUnsafe(string message, string title, Buttons buttons, IconImage icon)
```

**Step 2:** Add a static property `MainForm` inside the class `MsgBox`.

```
public static Form MainForm { get; set; }
```

**Step 3:** Add the line bellow inside the constructor of the main form of your application:

```
MsgBox.MainForm = this;
```

**Step 4:** Add a new method `Show` inside the class `MsgBox`.

```
public static MsgDlgResult Show(string message, string title, Buttons buttons, IconImage icon)
{
    if (!MainForm.IsHandleCreated) return default(MsgDlgResult);
    if (MainForm.InvokeRequired)
    {
        MsgDlgResult result = default(MsgDlgResult);
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        MainForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { result = ShowSafe(message, title, buttons, icon); });
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return ShowSafe(message, title, buttons, icon);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but the problem is that I have to return MsgDlgResult and this is not possible in the Invoke line.

Comment: @Fellnase you are right, I forgot the return value. I updated my answer.

Comment: I still get an error from the compiler that result gets no new value

Comment: @Fellnase once more you are right, sorry. I shouldn't post code without testing it first. I updated my answer again.